# processing HTTPS requests and ZeroMQ messages in parallel inside Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, zeromq

I am trying to do two things in parallel:

- intercept HTTPS POST request and make Twisted hold the connection open indefinitely (return `NOT_DONE_YET`)
- listen to ZeroMQ queue (and close one of the pending connections as a result of a ZeroMQ message)

I know how to make each of these two things separately, but how can I do them in parallel? To be specific, how can I receive messages from ZeroMQ inside the Twisted framework, when I am already listening to TCP sockets?

Comment: It seems you need good Twisted tutorial. Twisted is all about doing many things at once...

Comment: Actually that is what I was doing for a whole day, but I was unable to find an example on how to listen to multiple different events concurrently. If you know of a good tutorial, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `Twisted` (concurrently) puts each event in the reactor event loop, and after each event the appropriate callback is being executed. Notice, however, that there is no work being done in parallel - if there are multiple callbacks in queue they will be done consecutively.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but I did know that. I just had a hard time finding an example or tutorial on how to listen to both TCP and ZMQ connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can get support for ZMQ [here, in txZMQ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txZMQ/).

It sounds like you already know how to deal with the HTTP request.

To do these things in parallel, just create your `ZmqSubConnection` and your `twisted.web.server.Site`, with references to each other as necessary for your application.  No special set-up is required.

Just make sure you only create and run *one* reactor.  Other people with similar questions sometimes don't understand that `reactor.run()` means "run the event loop for the whole process", and not "run this one thing I set up".

Comment: Thanks, Glyph - I have already solved my problem by using Tornado (Twisted was just too... twisted for my taste :) ), but it might help someone else with a similar issue.